# Converting latLng to screen point

Tags: coordinate-system, pixel, mercator

I have a map in RN app on iOS and I have and overlay outside of the map

Inside overlay I need to draw a View with some absolute position that will match some LatLng coords on the map

I know screen size (map takes the whole screen)

```
{"height": 852, "width": 393}
```

I know current map Region:

```
{
  "latitude": 59.43746671032121,
  "latitudeDelta": 0.060761534486239555,
  "longitude": 24.765301670401954,
  "longitudeDelta": 0.061873817932173836
}
```

I have this point on the map:

```
{"latitude": 59.4378221, "longitude": 24.76909}
```

Is it possible to get x/y value?

with x it's easy:

```
const pointPixelX =
    ((point.longitude - region.longitude) / region.longitudeDelta) *
      windowWidth +
    windowWidth / 2;
```

And it works correctly.

For y I understand the complexity of Mercator projection and I have y value close to correct, but when I drag the map, my overlay marker moves far away from correct position.